# Example of RESTful API in Flask Python

Tags: python, rest, api, flash-message

Can someone show me examples of making a RESTful API which uses database information in Flask? I have no idea how to implement POST, PUT and DELETE and I always get the 405 error where I can't use the method in url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you add request method in your routing? you can following reference from: [flask-restful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api)

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class TodoSimple(Resource):
    def get(self):
        # do get something

    def put(self):
        # do put something

    def delete(self):
        # do delete something

    def post(self):
        # do post something

api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/api/todo')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I kinda did it like that, but I made separate classes for every method. It's just I don't know how to use POST, DELETE AND PUT in mine.I basically queried the database for GET, but the for the other 3 im not sure what i need to put.

Comment: GET: load data
POST: Insert data

Comment: please see this link : https://github.com/amingolmahalle/TodoFlask

Answer (score 0):

in flask-restful the HTTP actions (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE) have their corresponding method in the resource class, so is just a matter of defining those method in the resource (with the corresponding parameter defined in the routing)

I've also built a lightweight framework for building restful apis that makes it super easy to build apis. You can take a look at the code to have an idea of how an API can be built, configured and run, and of course, build on top of it

here's the code: https://github.com/sebastiandev/peach